# Json unicode issue

Tags: python, json, windows, unicode, python-3.4

I have some non-ASCII characters in a json file. There is a list and that list has strings like `SMΛN`. When I read json file and print that list

```
with open ("strings.json") as f:
    t = json.load(f)

print (t)
```

I got that non-ASCII string like `'SMÎ›N\n'`. How can I decode it as `utf-8` or something like I can print unicode characters properly? I tried this

```
with open ("strings.json",encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    t = json.load(f).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

But the output is still same.

Comment: What does `locale` tell? It is one problem to have the unicode encoded as bytes in the file, and the other decoding on read in the reading environment and then again encoding for output (which should depend on locale with print)

Comment: It could also be that the file you are reading is not UTF-8. Are you sure that is the correct encoding?

Comment: @syntonym I took the data from a .txt file and then `json.dump()`, then read it from json as above. The file is encoded utf-8 I'm sure about that

Comment: @David Yes it's Windows-7

Comment: What happens if you open the file as binary? (so that the decoding is done by the json library)

Comment: FWIW, `'SMΛN'.encode('utf8').decode('cp1252')` results in `'SMÎ›N'`; and `'SMÎ›N'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')` results in `'SMΛN'`. Also, `'SMΛN'.encode('utf8')` results in `b'SM\xce\x9bN'`

Comment: @PM2Ring Well you're right. Could you post your comment as answer please

Comment: @GLHF Sorry, I was just noting the relationship between those two strings. I don't have an actual answer to the cause of your problem, although I assume it has something to do with your console using codepage 1252. Does David's answer work for you? I can't test it because I don't use Windows.

Comment: What do you get from `print(b'SM\xce\x9bN'.decode('utf8'))` in the terminal? If the terminal's encoding is UTF-8, you should get `SMΛN`, but if the encoding is codepage 1252 you will get  `SMÎ›N`. So the proper solution is to set the correct encoding in the terminal. That's very easy to do in my terminal, but I have no idea of how to do it on a Windows system.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, `open` defaults to using the encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding()` which on US-localized Windows is `cp1252`.

Open the file with UTF-8 encoding instead:

```
#coding:utf8
import json
L = ['SMΛN']

# Generate an example file in UTF-8.
with open('out.json','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    json.dump(L,f,ensure_ascii=False)

# open with default encoding
with open('out.json') as f:
    L = json.load(f)

print(L)

# open with correct encoding
with open('out.json', encoding='utf8') as f:
    L = json.load(f)

print(L)
```

Output:

```
['SMÎ›N']
['SMΛN']
```

Note that the print will only work correctly if your IDE (and font) supports Unicode characters being printed.

P.S. `chcp 65001` to view the output on Windows console as suggested in another answer *is* broken (Note the extra `]` line.  This was Windows 7):

```
C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>test
['SMÎ›N']
]
['SMΛN']
```